# Mongodb nodejs query syntax error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to have query like this :

This query will select one document in the friendrequest collection where either the sender_id equals "id1" AND receiver_id equals "id2" OR sender_id equals = "id2" AND receiver_id equals "id1"

So can anyone help me to build that query ?

select * from friendrequest where (sender_id = "id1" and receiver_id = "id2") OR (receiver_id = "id1" and sender_id = "id2") for mySql

Error:

```
friendRequests.findOne({$or:[{$and:[{sender_id:req.body._id,receiver_id:req.body._uid2}],$and:[{sender_id:req.body._uid2,receiver_id:req.body._id}]}
```

Comment: Sounds pretty straightforward; what are you trying that's giving you a syntax error?

Comment: actually I couldnt complete the querry it will end like this :) I'll edit my question@JohnnyHK

Comment: Looks like you posted the query you tried but I don't see the error the query gave you

Comment: it should return a result from query  { result : null } @metame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple terms in the same object are implicitly $and'ed, so it just needs to be:

```
friendRequests.findOne({$or:[
    {sender_id:req.body._id, receiver_id:req.body._uid2},
    {sender_id:req.body._uid2, receiver_id:req.body._id}
]})
```